# iOS7 orientation and 1px white border

Tags: ios7, orientation, border

I have noticed a strange bug that appears when switching between Landscape and Portrait orientation with iOS7. I wasn't able to find any discussion about this - hopefully this is already solved and I am blind?

I am working on a site, but I have noticed this error on some awwward winning sites as well. If you go to http://www.toolofna.com/#/work on an iPad with iOS7, and switch from Landscape to Portrait and then back to Landscape again, a 1px line appears on the bottom.

I noticed on another site that if you scroll above the site content (so the ipad 'snaps' the content back), this resolved the issue.

This seems to be an iOS7 bug. I have tried using window.scrollTo(0,0) but this does not solve it. Any thoughts?